# Using word interop create multiple documents from a template for print preview

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I have an app where the user selects from a list all the students they want to print an award document for.

I have a template .doc file that contains 3 text boxes that I populate from code. I can populate the file and show it in the print preview for a single student, but based on how many students are selected I want to create a large document with many pages I can see in print preview before printing and print all at once.

The following is my attempt to turn my working code for a single word document being created from the template to show in print preview. Any ideas?

```
        public void AddStudentToDocument(IEnumerable<StudentToPrint> studentsToPrint )
    {
        _Application oWordApp = new Application();

        string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

        string specificFolder = Path.Combine(folder, "FoothillsAcademy");
        string fileLocation = Path.Combine(specificFolder, "CertTemplate.doc");

        if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
        {
            var oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(fileLocation);
            oWordDoc.Activate();
            oWordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph();

            foreach (var studentToPrint in studentsToPrint)
            {

            _Document oDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add();
            Selection oSelection = oWordApp.Selection;

            string docText = oWordDoc.Content.Text;

            if (docText != null)
            {
                int boxNumber = 1;
                foreach (Shape shape in oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
                {
                    if (shape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)
                    {
                        if (boxNumber == 1)
                        {
                            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = studentToPrint.StudentName;
                        }
                        if (boxNumber == 2)
                        {
                            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = studentToPrint.Rank;
                        }
                        if (boxNumber == 3)
                        {
                            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = studentToPrint.DateAcheved;
                        }

                        boxNumber++;
                    }
                }

                _Document oCurrentDocument = oWordApp.Documents.Add(oWordDoc);
                copyPageSetup(oCurrentDocument.PageSetup, oDoc.Sections.Last.PageSetup);
                oCurrentDocument.Range().Copy();
                oSelection.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
                //if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(oWordDoc.Content, oWordDoc.Last()))
                    oSelection.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
            }

            oWordApp.Visible = true;
            oWordApp.ShowStartupDialog = true;
            oWordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintPreview();

            }
        }
    }

private void copyPageSetup(PageSetup source, PageSetup target)
        {
            target.PaperSize = source.PaperSize;

            if (!source.Orientation.Equals(target.Orientation))
                target.TogglePortrait();

            target.TopMargin = source.TopMargin;
            target.BottomMargin = source.BottomMargin;
            target.RightMargin = source.RightMargin;
            target.LeftMargin = source.LeftMargin;
            target.FooterDistance = source.FooterDistance;
            target.HeaderDistance = source.HeaderDistance;
            target.LayoutMode = source.LayoutMode;
        }

 public class StudentToPrint
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string Rank { get; set; }
        public string DateAcheved { get; set; }
    }
```

Currently I am testing this with a collection of StudentsToPrint added below. Based on the data below I would expect to see 3 certificates personalized for each of the 3 students. Each certificate would be on its own page.

```
List<StudentToPrint> listOfStudents = new List<StudentToPrint>
                    {
                        new StudentToPrint
                            {
                                DateAcheved = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                                Rank = "5th Degree",
                                StudentName = "Scott LaFoy"
                            },
                            new StudentToPrint
                            {
                                DateAcheved = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                                Rank = "3rd Degree",
                                StudentName = "John Doe"
                            },
                            new StudentToPrint
                            {
                                DateAcheved = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                                Rank = "2nd Degree",
                                StudentName = "Jane Doe"
                            }
                    };
```

The template is a word doc that has 3 text boxes. Using the text box lets me set font and position different for each of them as well as making the background transparent so the template background shows through. I am sure there is another way to do this as well but there is not much on this topic around.

Comment: I know its possible and shouldn't be this hard. Does anyone know of a wrapper that that might be a little easier to work with?

Comment: I will explain you what is the problem here: you are coming from a completely wrong approach. I try to fix small bits but wrong results keep appearing (because your whole approach is wrong). I don't to redo your whole code (this is not what SO is about) and, as a reward, I have to work under not-too-sensible conditions (correcting problems which shouldn't be there, because are provoked by a basic wrong implementation). I guess that I am a horrible answerer for this kind of questions, but I am always intending to help. Now I will write down a summary of the problems, to see what I mean...

Comment: ... your code does not clearly separate the two sets of documents (template and new ones being generated). My answer provided a first solution on this front, but was just fictitiously good, as far as your structure is bad and needs to be redone. You have to create two word apps/docs (as suggested): first one will be a blank file (var oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add();... it has to be saved as a different name oWordDoc.SaveAs2(specificFolder + @"\output.docx");) and second one will open the template (_Document oDoc = oWordApp2.Documents.Open(fileLocation);)

Comment: I hope that you will understand that intending to help someone with the ideas not too clear and by relying on a code with quite a few problems is not what this is about (at least, not the kind of help I want to provide). You don't have a specific problem, not even a bunch of them; but not-clear-at-all ideas which output and highly unreliable and overall problematic code. I think that the best help you can get is starting from scratch and doing things step by step: clear separation of elements (document from/to) and of steps to be given. What you aim is (very) easy with right attitude...

Comment: ... saying that you didn't find anything is the same than saying that you seriously expect to find anything: there are no already-done solutions for your problems; you have to build your own ones. If you do that (looking for made solutions), you would get to a situation like the current one: a code with a poor structure, not delivering what you want and requiring to be completely redone. But this is just what I think. Feel free to do what you want. I hope that anything of this has been of help.